# Stepping stone from vectors to surfaces in multivariable/vector calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, surfaces

I'm trying to study Vector Calculus, and think that the [book by Michael Corral](http://www.mecmath.net/calc3book.pdf), is a wonderful book. I went through the first few chapters with ease, but I came across something entirely not included in any of my math studies up until now - surfaces. The chapter that follows is marked curvilinear coordinates.

There's not much description or proofs about how the equations of surfaces came to be, just equation representations of 3-dimensional surfaces. I also have a secondary book (Thomas' calculus), which pretty much does the same thing. By now, I am completely lost how to continue my studies on this? What would be a stepping stone for my level of knowledge of the usual vectors to these completely new subject matters?

Comment: @JW, I don't know how to go through the transition from 1.5 to 1.6, it's like a sudden jump.

Comment: Paul's Online Notes - go to that website you'll learn so much about it, gives you foundation in Calc 2 and then very good explaination in Calc 3

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just deleted my comment though, as I realised it was obvious where you were up to. In part, I was misled by the use of the term "chapter" instead of "section".

Comment: The Math Insight thread on [multivariable calculus](http://mathinsight.org/thread/multivar) may be helpful, as may the thread on [vector algebra](http://mathinsight.org/thread/vector_algebra). In the latter, note the sections on visualizing functions in higher dimensions and coordinate systems.

Comment: @JW, Regarding section 1.5 and 1.6, the topics seem in the sequence no matter which reference I see, first quadratic surfaces and then curvilinear coordinates, Do you think the latter should be studied first?

Comment: Would http://mathinsight.org/thread/quadric_gallery help, perhaps?

Comment: @JW, they however don't seem to be on the same line, it's included in our calculus 1st sem course syllabus, but are at a seperate unit from Vector and vector valued functions(These include the topic: Vectors in space, lines and planes in space, cylinders and quadratic surfaces, Cylindrical and spherical coordinates, vector and vector valued functions and space curves, unit tangent vectors and TNB system), and then it moves to multivariable calculus.

Comment: Just to get a better idea of where you are stuck, if you go back to two-dimensional space, can you explain where the equation of a circle of radius $r$ centred on the origin, $x^2+y^2=r^2$, comes from?

Comment: @JW, we did learn a bit about the derivation of the circle's equation, even before joining high school; most probably in optional maths' classes. But, there was nothing from spheres..........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50890/discussion-between-j-w-and-lind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Section 1.6 of [Corral](http://www.mecmath.net/calc3book.pdf) on surfaces, especially quadric surfaces, the stepping stone you might need is to go over [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) (i.e. circles, ellipses, parabolas and hyperbolas) again. You can temporarily set the material on vectors aside - it will return soon enough in Section 1.8 on vector-valued functions. Start with the [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) and see whether the equation of a circle of radius $r$ centred on the origin makes sense:

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

It is based on Pythagoras' Theorem and captures the idea of the set of all points $(x,y)$ of distance $r>0$ from the origin $(0,0)$, measured using the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) in the plane. If you prefer, you could write it as

$$(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 = r^2$$

or

$$\sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2} = r$$

Similarly, the equation of a circle of radius $r$ centred on $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$$

Going up one dimension, we have the equation of a sphere of radius $r$ centred on $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, measured using the Euclidean distance in three dimensions:

$$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2$$

From here, you can investigate the other conic sections and then the [quadric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric), perhaps with the aid of Math Insight's [quadrics page](http://mathinsight.org/quadric_surfaces).

Answer (score 1):

Most students don't go from calculus to vector calculus; you need to look into linear algebra.  Take a gander [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/).

Comment: Most students where, if you don't mind me asking? While linear algebra is certainly an important subject for mathematics students, the Calculus I-III sequence common in the US seems to include a light introduction to vectors, lines and planes at the beginning of Calculus III, which should be enough to study introductory multivariable and vector calculus, without needing a full-blown course on linear algebra.

Comment: At my undergraduate school, certainly, linear algebra was a requirement for vector calculus.  I didn't go to US public school, so I couldn't say what's generally taught at the high school level.

Answer (score 1):

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/

Try these notes. I don't know how much you know but all the material is really good here and it's free. There are very lengthy introductions about how to parametrise surfaces, what surfaces are, and all you need for a vector calculus course. Stuff in Vector Calculus will be at the end of Calculus 2 and in Calculus 3.

There are also sections covering the topics in Linear Algebra that you need to know. Otherwise, if you really need more algebra you can go on youtube and watch MIT Linear Algebra by Strang

Comment: the content design is flawlessly arrange, but, It's just like M corral's book I've mentioned, after planes' knowledge, it heads on to quadratic surfaces, and there's no description of the origin of these surfaces or derivations or proofs,

Comment: Am I making a mistake for the page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx     ?

Comment: @lind mmmh okay.. let me think about some better text, if I can find any